# SSRS Export to Word with Heading 1 Style

Tags: .net, reporting-services, ms-word, ssrs-2008-r2, rdl

I have a textbox in SSRS report to which I need to apply style of MS Word.

Basically on Export the text in the Text box should have heading 1 style.

[image]

I referred **Applying Style Properties to Report Items** https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156380(v=sql.90).aspx  from msdn but did not find any solution

I tried with `<H1>`  tag in placeholder. Though it applies the styles it never exports to the Heading1 style of word.

I need Heading 1 style so that i can create TOC easily from word.

Comment: Is there a way to achieve this.. or we have to wait for Microsoft to provide an option to get this done. Please have your say.

Comment: I had a similar issue years ago. I ended up building an entire application. I would add 'tags' to sections of the report for headers etc. Then the application would go thru the exported document and replace the tags with heading styles. Our reports were complex and long but we could fully format a doc that was hundreds of pages long based on a template with all the styles defined. You might also want to look at Aspose Words, they do an SSRS renderer that 'might' be able to do a little more than the standard one.